# While using Couchbase Java SDK, why don't we provide a username and why doesn't password work?

Tags: java, couchbase

I have been trying to use the java jdk to Couchbase. sdk v 3.2.3 
However I find it strange that the examples provided never supply any password while connecting. Also I created a read-only user, and I see that the there is nowhere to provide the user-name while opening a bucket from a cluster, you only provide the password. I tried using the password for the admin and for the read-only user that I created. But it would fail with couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "myBucket" do not match. It is the same password that I use when I login to the admin console, yet this password doesnot work. Only the empty password works.

I am confused and don't get the hang of it?

Anybody knows about this?

My aim was to create a read-only user and use this user credentials to only read data from couchbase for a specific module which is only supposed to read data.

Comment: from the Admin console, it seems we can set a password on a bucket (which is not associated to a user, but directly to a bucket.) So that explains why we don't provide a user-name, and only just the password. But still unable to understand how accomplish a read-only connection to a couchbase bucket.

Comment: On the documentation page (http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/security/security-author-apps.html)  ... there is this sentence : "Applications use bucket passwords to authenticate to a Couchbase bucket, and then they obtain complete read-write access to it."    I think this means that there is no such thing as a read-only connection ... Please comment if someone has some insight into this .

Comment: If you can tolerate a paid solution, there are 3rd party drivers available. Our [JDBC driver](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/couchbase/jdbc) authenticates at the user level (not the bucket level) and then translates the SQL request into a N1QL request that is submitted using the Web API.

Comment: HI @JerodJohnson, I shall go through your link. I will take a look at it and decide ...

Comment: Also refer to this, incase someone's curious : https://forums.couchbase.com/t/n1ql-readonly-permissions/6420

Comment: Hi, @JerodJohnson I have gone through the couchbase jdbc driver. I didnot understand how one could do an authentication and provide only a read-only access. Could you point me to some documentation there ?

Comment: Our driver doesn't directly provide read-only access. But since we authenticate at the user level, you should be able to create a read-only user in Couchbase and then authenticate with that user. If you have more questions, our [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, there is no read only data access to a bucket in Couchbase. Stay tuned as there will be lots of security changes in the coming versions of Couchbase.

Comment: okay. I believe having seperate writable and readonly access is an essential feature . Thank you for your reply. Hope this comes soon